# Firebase single call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm using firebase in a React application and I'm having a bit of an issue.

I'm querying N items from my collection. But in this particular query I'm not interested in the real-time aspects of Firebase, since I'm loading the data into the state of my component and the event listener makes the state constantly refresh changing the page content (which I don't want).

So, is there a way to make a "static" query as you would do with MongoDb or any other non real-time DBs?.

Also is there a way to retrieve all elements from a collection at once without having to listen for changes? I'm using it right now like this:

```
postsRef.startAt().orderByChild('likes')
        .on(
          'child_added',
          (snapshot) => {
            this.setState({
              media: [...this.state.media, snapshot.val()],
            });
          },
        );
```

But its far from ideal since I'm getting them one by one and I would prefer to get a single array or object with all of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all items in one go, use `on('value'` or `once('value'`. This gives you a snapshot of all matching child nodes in one go. You then use `Snapshot.forEach()` to loop over the results:

```
postsRef.startAt().orderByChild('likes')
        .on(
          'value',
          (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((child) => {
              this.setState({
                media: [...this.state.media, child.val()],
              });
            });
          },
        );
```